# Replace values from other columns if value of one column is null using awk/sed

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I am trying to modify a tab delimited file by replacing the value of 2 columns separated by ":" where there is a null value in one column:

Start with this file:

```
id1 id2 pos1    pos2
749 2847443 21  13517135
862 2821796 21  13571669
997     21  13636494
1095    2821826 21  13661335
1131        21  13678797
```

I would like to modify column 2 to get this:

```
id1 id2 pos1    pos2
749 2847443 21  13517135
862 2821796 21  13571669
997 21:13636494 21  13636494
1095    2821826 21  13661335
1131    21:13678797 21  13678797
```

The problem is also that there is no blank space (" ") indicating a null value. 
For now I have not even been able to substitute the value of column 2 with column 3 when it is null...

I have tried using sed:

```
sed -e 's/\t\t/\t$3\t/g' input.txt > output
```

Which works but it just substitutes the text '$3' and I can't find how to substitute the values of $3:$4 instead.

I have also tried awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  IFS = OFS = "\t"
 }
{
    for (column = 2; column <= NF; ++column) {
    if ($column == "") {
        $column = $3
    }
 }    
 print 
}         
'
input.txt > output
```

But this does not work either (it does nothing actually neither using "" nor " "...)

Can you please help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

checking null value is actually easy. but I didn't understand the requirement well. which column could be null? in your awk script, you have loop from $2->$NF, if there is null column, you didn't set to ":" separated values, but set with $3. what about $3 is null?

I assume that only $2 (column2) could be null, then the following awk line should do the job.

```
 awk -F'\t' -vOFS='\t' '!$2{$2=$3":"$4}1' file
```

**test**

```
<ff is your input file>

kent$  awk -F'\t' -vOFS='\t' '!$2{$2=$3":"$4}1' ff          
id1     id2     pos1    pos2
749     2847443 21      13517135
862     2821796 21      13571669
997     21:13636494     21      13636494
1095    2821826 21      13661335
1131    21:13678797     21      13678797
```

to see it clearly, we could pipe the output to column command:

```
kent$  awk -F'\t' -vOFS='\t' '!$2{$2=$3":"$4}1' ff|column -t
id1   id2          pos1  pos2
749   2847443      21    13517135
862   2821796      21    13571669
997   21:13636494  21    13636494
1095  2821826      21    13661335
1131  21:13678797  21    13678797
```

hope it is helpful for you.

Comment: This works (without the -v, just -OFS) Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

looking at the before/after text you posted

```
B:    997       21  13636494
A:    997   21:13636494 21  13636494
```

you want to replace the 2nd column *if null*
with the `3rd + '**:**' + 4th column`, right ?

so go for this:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\t\t\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/\1\t\2:\3\t\2\t\3/g' testfile
```

that is match the line which has

> something tabtab something tab something

and replace it with

> 1st-column tab 3rd-column:4th-column tab 3rd-column tab 4th-column

example:

```
$ cat testfile
749 2847443 21  13517135
862 2821796 21  13571669
997     21  13636494
1095    2821826 21  13661335
1131        21  13678797

$ sed 's/\(.*\)\t\t\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/\1\t\2:\3\t\2\t\3/g' testfile
749 2847443 21  13517135
862 2821796 21  13571669
997 21:13636494 21  13636494
1095    2821826 21  13661335
1131    21:13678797 21  13678797
```

Note: this looks for a missing 2nd column only, as what you talked about

PS: if you think that answers your question, don't forget to mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Hi, the sed code is not working (it is not changing the input file) so I'll use Kent's code using the awk but thank you for your code and explanations. I'm still wondering why it shouldn't work but there may be something odd with my text…